# Runing a cpp binary on php could speed up my code?

Tags: php, c++

I'm a php developer as well as cpp developer. I was wondering: if I make a cpp binary and I run it on php. Will that make my process run faster?

For example:

I have to compare 1,000 array elements and execute a process for each of them and in some cases I had to run it over and over again ( recursively) .   Yes is messup but it works !.

Comment: Calling an external executable via `exec` or the like? That's one awkward way to integrate functionality written in a different language. Anyway, performance problems in this code don't come from a language implementation's raw performance, they come from a totally batshit insane algorithm (at least it sounds like one)... fixing that will yield way more speedup than this headache can possibly give!

Comment: You can code a module in C++ and include it like any php module, but it's no easy task. (also, I don't really know where to look, I just know it's possible, hence the comment instead of an answer)

Comment: @cambraca - I think most PHP modules are coded in C rather than in C++

Comment: @Mark Baker, any C++ library can expose a C interface using `extern "C"`.

Comment: @Mark I don't know much about all this, but AFAIK C is even better if the OP only wants to do basic stuff with arrays, right?

Comment: @cambraca: it rather depends what has to be done. C++ can do anything C does, but often does it at the same speed using less code.

Comment: @larsmans: I wouldn't bet on me winning an argument against that :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, this might be faster. It's also very hard to do right (lots of corner cases in IPC).
2. Don't try this unless it's absolutely necessary for performance. First try to improve the algorithm in PHP.
3. Don't use the C++ code in production until you've measured the difference, and the C++ solution is significantly faster.
4. Don't run a binary, write a library and [link it into the PHP interpreter](http://www.php.net/~wez/extending-php.pdf). PHP is implemented in C, so export your C++ functions to C using `extern "C"`.

Answer (score 1):

I never did that in php, but in python I can tell you that it's a hell of a good way to squeeze performance. But don't overdo it: just implement in C what you *know* is a bottleneck, otherwise you will just create a monster.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to profile your code first and make sure you've actually identified the bottleneck. If its working now, it should be easy to include XDebug in your code so that you can measure its performance and profile your function calls. Maybe your function call isn't the bottleneck, in which case all your work would be wasted.

After that, see if there are any architectural issues before you switch languages. If there is a scalability problem, switching over to a faster language will just delay the issue.